# no recibo valores desde el controller en MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, sql-server, mvc, entity-framework

estoy haciendo una aplicación en MVC 5, con entity framework 6.0, que en base a una fecha seleccionada, envié esta fecha a un controller que la pasa a un procedimiento almacenado , este procedimiento en base a esa fecha, cuenta la cantidad de personas y devuelve el valor al controller y "supuestamente" debería pasarlo nuevamente al ajax, para que mediante javascript pueda procesarlo y mostrar el resultado en la vista; el código es el siguiente:

```
$("#FechConsult").change('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'Json',
            url: "/Home/CuentaUser",
            data: { FechaInsc: $("#FechConsult").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                var CantidadUsr = result[0];
                $("#TotCupos").val(CantidadUsr.CantiPer);
                cupos = ParseInt(CantidadUsr.CantiPer - TotalUsr);
                if ((cupos >= 15) || (cupos <= 20)) {
                    $("#TotCupos").css({ "background": "#b5ff33" });
                }
                else {
                    if ((cupos >= 10) || (cupos <= 14)) {
                        $("#TotCupos").css({ "background": "#e9f00e" });
                    }
                    else {
                        if ((cupos >= 1) || (cupos <= 9)) {
                            $("#TotCupos").css({ "background": "#e85e0a" });
                            $("#mensaje").show();
                            $("#mensaje").val("Ha Llegado Casi Al Limite de Cupos Diarios");
                        }
                        else {
                            if ((cupos = TotalUsr)) {
                                $("#mensaje").show();
                                $("#mensaje").val("Ha Llegado A Límite Máximo de Personas, Seleccione Otro Dia");
                                $("#PassWord").focus();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

después esto pasa al controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CuentaUser(Inscripcion inscripcion)
        {
            using (CtaUsr = new Drillco_InscripcionEntities())
            {
                var CantiPer =  CtaUsr.SP_Sel_Cta_PersXFecha(Convert.ToString(inscripcion.FechaInsc));
                return Json(CantiPer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

El Procedimiento almacenado es como sigue:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_Sel_Cta_PersXFecha]
@FechInsc varchar(10)
as
Begin
      select COUNT(idOper) AS CantP
      from Inscripcion
      where FechaInsc = CONVERT(datetime, @FechInsc, 103)
end
```

el problema:  consiste en que después de llamar al procedimiento almacenado , el ajax no me recibe el valor devuelto por el controller, al hacer F12 en el navegador, me indica que hay un error 500 y no me reconoce el nombre del controller, le he dado mil vueltas y no he llegado a ninguna solución, alguien podría indicarme que estoy haciendo mal????.

saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo Solucioné , como :  en el controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CuentaUsuarios(Inscripcion inscripcion)
        {
            using (CtaUsr = new Drillco_InscripcionEntities())
            {
                var CantiPer =  CtaUsr.SP_Sel_Cta_PersXFecha(Convert.ToString(inscripcion.FechaInsc));
               return Json(CantiPer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
           
            }
        }
```

cambie la llamada al SP , le agregue lo siguiente:

```
var CantiPer =  CtaUsr.SP_Sel_Cta_PersXFecha(Convert.ToString(inscripcion.FechaInsc)).ToList();
```

y ahí el dato paso como y adonde debía.